# Excel And VB.NET Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm working on a VB.NET web app and I need to create Excel files, but I'm working on a Virtual Machine and I can't install Microsoft Office on it ... 
Any Idea to add my references ??

Thanks !

Comment: You can use Excel COM Interop. Try this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_excel_sheet.htm

Comment: @etaiso Doesn't that require installing Excel? Krishnak, why can't you just install Excel? It's going to be very difficult to get Excel interop going without Excel to interop with...

Comment: @CodyGray you are correct, I thought maybe there is a way getting the library without installing Excel.

Comment: The reference Microsoft Excel that i could see in a lot of tutorial does'nt appear on my virtual machine, so I can't do anything .
@CodyGray I can't because i'm not Admin on the machine >< And I've got only 200Mo on free memory (I'm a Student in a Cie to pass my year (Sorry for my english i'm French :p))

Comment: @Krishnak probably I was wrong and you must have Excel installed. Maybe try looking for open source projects.

Comment: I'm also trying to intall Excel Viewver but it doesn't work

Comment: The install of the Excel Viewer had finally work, and I could find now Microsoft Office Interop, so it's finally work !

Comment: @Krishnak Please post your solution as an answer so it can help future people with the same problem

Comment: @SysDragon In one hour I could, I'm under the ten reputation required to answer my own question ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use COM Interop you will need to install Excel (office)

An alternative is to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which does not require Office

Answer (score 0):

you need to have Microsoft Excel installed in order to have access to the Introp libraries that you need to add as references to your project in order to make it work.

or

[npoi](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The install of the Excel Viewer had finally work, and I could find now Microsoft Office Interop!